# Why my deep learning model always give an output of 1 class?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I'm training a CNN model on Keras to classify images belong to 2 classes. I have about 600 images of class 0 and 1000 images of class 1. My model is shown below. The problem is it always gave me the output of the class with higher samples. I tried to change the last activation function into sigmoid but it did not help at all. I also tried to add batch normalization as well as regularization and dropout.

```
def model(input_shape):
    #Define the input placeholder as a tensor with shape input_shape
    X_input = Input(input_shape)
    # First layer
    X = Conv2D(32,(5,5),strides=(1,1),padding='same',name='conv1')(X_input)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    X = MaxPooling2D((3,3),strides=2,name='pool1')(X)

# Second layer
    X = Conv2D(32,(5,5),strides=(1,1),padding='same',name='conv2')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    X = AveragePooling2D((3,3),strides=2,name='pool2')(X)

# Third layer
    X = Conv2D(64,(5,5),strides=(1,1),padding='same',name='conv3')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    X = AveragePooling2D((3,3),strides=2,name='pool3')(X)

# Flatten
    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(64,activation='softmax',name='fc1')(X)
    X = dropout(0.5)(X)
    X = Dense(2,activation='softmax',name='fc2')(X)

# Create the model
    model = Model(inputs = X_input,outputs = X)

    return model
```

Comment: Have you normalized your data?

Comment: What is your data about? Is it cars? cats? or something related to biology? It is also important to have any information about the data.

Comment: @FalconUA it is tumor histopathological image. There are 2 classes: malignant and benign.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko yes I did, of course.

Comment: Both training and validation?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko yes, I normalized both using imagegenerator from keras

Comment: What is your data classes balance (percentage of different classes in your dataset)? Maybe your data is imbalanced and model is encouraged to give only one decision?

Comment: Two softmax layers in succession seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have a 2-class **classification** problem, where the number of samples in the classes are **imbalanced**. This problem is especially common for medical diagnostics, and causes a lot of headache not only to you.

You have stated that the specific problem you are solving is classifying tumor histopathological images. These images are very rich in patterns, so 1600 images in total is typically not enough to learn meaningful features and representations. The distribution in minibatches is also imbalanced, so the gradient will always be slightly shifted (given that other filters are producing random noise since they didn't have time to learn meaningful features) towards the local minimum of one-class classification.

There are, however, several techniques to improve the performance:

- **Trim the larger class**, so that the number of samples in each class is roughly the same. So in your case, reduce the class with 1000 samples to around 600.
- If you don't want to train on less data, try **assign a weight to each class**. [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras) is a link to short example. So, in your specific case, you have `600` images of class `A` and `1000` images of class `B`. So, you can assign a weight `1.0` for class B and `10/6` to class A.
- As stated above, 1600 samples is not enough to learn meaningful features. Especially when you have a Deep Neural Network. So, what you can try is **Transfer Learning**. A very detailed tutorial (which was one on SO Documentation) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389215/4789373). Make sure to look closely at the layer's visualization in the tutorial.
- Also, to test the model's capability, you might want to try **intentional overfitting**. A quick checklist can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45342936/4789373).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried augmentation and undersampling to get class balance in the training set. I divide my set into training set, val set and test set. There is original and augmented data in the training and val set, but the test set contains only original data. The result I get on the val set after tuning is ~90% but when I use the test set, it only gives 76%. My question is if the augmented data affects this result? Data augmentation includes flip horizontal and vertical, add noise and blur.